# Windows 10 scheduled php task not working

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I've made a Weather script that downloads the weather forecast from worldweatheronline.com and copy it to my database. My local CakePhp Shell / script is working correctly when I execute it via Git Bash.

Now I want to automatically update the weather script on my local machine with a Windows 10 task. My task seems to run (I've got a quick pop-up on my screen every five minutes), but the php script doesn't do anything.

My task settings are:

**Tab 'General'**

- Use the following useraccount to execute the task: sam_c
- Execute only when the user is logged in

**Tab 'Triggers'**

- Dayly
- Start 13/04/2017 21:32:00
- Repeat every: 5 min.
- During: 1 day

**Tab 'Action'**

- Action: Start program
- Program/script: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
- Parameters (optional): -f D:\Websites\BellewaerdeFun 2017\03 - Online\app\Console\Command\WeatherShell.php

**Tab 'Conditions', 'Settings' and 'History'**

- No changes

I guess the problem is in the tab 'Action'. I already tried to changed the parameters field to:

- -f D:/Websites/BellewaerdeFun 2017/03 - Online/app/Console/Command\WeatherShell.php
- php -f D:\Websites\BellewaerdeFun 2017\03 - Online\app\Console\Command\WeatherShell.php
- ...

Nothing seems to work. When I check the task history, it tells me that the task is completed. Liar :)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Sorry Jay, I didn't mean it that way :). I'm just wondering if my given parameters are right or not. That's why I'm asking for help ;)